# Fetchone() returns None, when there is only one row in resulting query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pgadmin-4

I'm using **pyscopg2** for connecting my flask application to my postgres database.

I'm having a weird situation

```
conn = self.engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)
   
sqlstr = f""" SELECT *  FROM name_table WHERE id = 22 """
       
res = conn.execute(sqlstr)
logger.info(res.fetchone())
conn.close()
self.engine.dispose()
```

The thing is `res.fetchone()` retuns me None value, but there is one row with data when I run the same query directly in pgadmin4.
The same fetchone returns me data when there are more than one row present in the result.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try: `res = conn.execute(sqlstr).fetchone()` then `logger.info(res)`.

Comment: It still returns `None`.

Comment: Then I'm going to say `name_table` is not what you think it is. Is the table name mixed or upper case in the database? If so you will need to double quote it.

Comment: Nope. If the table name is wrong, why is it returning me values when I don't use the where condition in the query? I problem is with the query returning single records, fetchone() is returning me null for one record

Comment: It is difficult to resolve the same query on the same database and schema working from one client but not another.  Please create a [mre].

Comment: I cannot reproduce, but then I don't know how you are setting up `logger`? Also what is field type for `id`? Add answers as update to your question.